# Hide elements when keyboard is open in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, keyboard, ionic3

What is the best practice to hide some elements of a page when the keyboard opens ?

For instance, I have a "reset password page", and when the keyboard opens to input the email in the field, the layout is messed up.

Comment: Here you can use this native Cordova plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/